# Closure chaining with multiple inner closures

Tags: groovy, types, return, type-conversion, closures

I am a newbie to groovy and closures.

I am trying to replicate the append function with groovy and after multiple trial and errors here is what I got working,

```
def storeAndPrint(x)  {
    x << {
        -> it + it
    }
    print x
    return this
}

storeAndPrint("G").storeAndPrint("o").storeAndPrint("ing")
```

I was trying to do the same with something below -

```
def storeAndPrint =  {
    it << {
        -> it + it
    }
    print it
    return this
}

storeAndPrint("G").storeAndPrint("o").storeAndPrint("ing")
```

which gives the below exception

```
GCaught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sample.groovy.GroovyMain.storeAndPrint() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [o]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sample.groovy.GroovyMain.storeAndPrint() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [o]
    at com.sample.groovy.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.groovy:22)
```

I am not sure I quite understood why the first one worked and why not the second one. And, secondly I am not sure if using the left shift operator is needed here or whether it could be done with out.

Thirdly, how can I split the method/function such that I get the same result when I do a

```
store("G").store("o").store("ing").printit()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not chaining closures.  you are just returning the wrapping class and call again the same method on it.  it's the same as `new StringBuffer().append("Go").append("ing").println()` but with the StringBuffer here beeing an implicitly created class from groovy wrapping your code.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks, how do I do it with closure chaining?

Comment: what is your goal here?  do you want to create a builder pattern?  or do you want to have the reference to the closure within the closure?

Comment: @cfrick reference to closure within closure and how it is to be invoked. Also to learn the scope of local and global variables/objects within the inner closures vs outer closures. Thanks for your time